# Passing multiple arguments into Django's filter()

Tags: python, sql, django

Based on user input I need to pass custom arguments into Django filter.

Something along the lines of the following:

```
q = Question.objects.all()
a = q.filter(O_Stat__icontains = "Active", Ll_Name__icontains = "fruit")
```

I tried setting the arguments to string:

```
f = 'Operating_Status__icontains = "Active", Legal_Name__icontains = "fruit"'
a = q.filter(f)
```

Get a stack trace error.
Is there a better solution then to pass every possible field into the filter ?

```
#Like This
a = q.filter(O_Stat__icontains = UserIn1, Ll_Name__icontains = UserIn2)
```

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a dict first and then use the keyword unpack operator `**` to pass the dict as keyword arguments to `filter`.

```
f = {'Operating_Status__icontains': "Active", 'Legal_Name__icontains': "fruit"}
a = q.filter(**f)
```